# Language to restrict a web search query to only search company websites

Tags: google-search, search-operators

I was wondering if there was a way to limit a Google web search query to only return company websites or to search an "about" page of a webpage?

For example, if I'm trying to find a company that manufactures engine control units (or ECUs), and I search for that, I get a lot of articles. Is it possible to limit or filter it for companies?

Comment: 1 specific company? Or company websites, so ignore forum posts, etc...?

Comment: any company website really. trying to avoid news articles/forums etc. Ideally looking for manufacturers and whole salers

Comment: Have a look at Google's [Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/).

Comment: @harrymc this appears to allow me to add a google search to my company website. I'm trying to search the entire web (or a general google search) for all companies that manufacture a specific product. Does the programmable search engine allow for this functionality?

Comment: You may specify in the engine the websites to search. It also creates a global search URL that does not depend on your website.

Comment: So looking into this further, i see how you can target the search to all urls, but how would i limit the search to only companies/corporations? Just trying to make sure i'm not missing something

Comment: If you are looking for a software recommendation try [softwarerecs.se] .To ask for [se] site recommendation ask a question on [meta.se]

Answer (score 0):

Google ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) doesn't offer a specific keyword to limit results to show only companies but they offer to companies / business ways to be listed. To learn more please checkout https://www.google.com/business/

It might be a good idea to try using the Shopping and the Maps tab. The first depends on the company / business, the second is a combination of crowdsourcing and business owners / representatives work.